# cli decompiler for java .class file

Tags: java, command-line-interface, decompiler

I am currently developing a program to analyse java source code. However I couldn't find any CLI decompilers to convert the .class files to java. Are there such programs? I have currently only found GUI based decompilers.

Comment: why not try javap command available with java itself

Comment: @Satya - because it doesn't convert bytecodes to Java ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few open-source actively developed CLI decompilers:

- [Procyon](https://github.com/mstrobel/procyon)
- [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)
- [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)